# Computing SNR with discrete random variables

Tags: signal-processing, probability

Suppose:

- The signal `S` is a random variable which takes the values `{0, 1, 2, 3}` with probabilities `{0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4}`.
- The noise `N` is a random variable which takes the values `{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}` with probabilities `{0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1}`.

The `SNR` is given by `(Power of S)/(Power of N) = ((Amplitude of S)/(Amplitude of N))^2`.

My question is: How is the amplitude of a random variable computed ? Is it:

- The Root-Mean_Square (RMS) amplitude ?
- The Variance ?

Comment: 1. This sounds like homework. What do you have so far? 2. This is not the kind of question that is well suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you got an answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `E[S^2]/E[N^2]` where `E` is the Expectation operator.